# Rerender component after function in provider ends

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, fetch, rendering, provider

I'm trying to set components with 3 functionalities. Displaying `PokemonList`, getting random pokemon and find one by filters. Getting random pokemon works great but since 2 days I'm trying to figure out how to set pokemon list feature correctly

Below full code from this component.
It's render when click `PokemonsList` button inside separate navigation component and fire `handleGetPokemonList` function in provider using context.

The problem is that I can't manage rerender components when `PokemonList` is ready. For now i need to additionally fire `forceUpadte()` function manually `(button onClick = () => forceUpdate())`
I tried to use `useEffect()` in `PokemonList` component but it didn't work in any way.
I was also sure that after fetching data with `fetchData()` function I can do .then(`changeState` of loading) but it didn't work also.

What Am I missing to automatically render data from fetch in provider in `PokemonList` component? I'm receiving error about no data exist but if I use `forceUpdate` then everything is ok

Complete repo here: https://github.com/Mankowski92/poke-trainer

`handleGetPokemonList` function in provider below

```
const handleGetPokemonList = () => {
    setCurrentPokedexOption('pokemonList');
    async function fetchData() {
      setImgLoaded(false);
      let res = await fetch(`${API}?offset=0&limit=6/`);
      let response = await res.json();
    
      response.results.forEach((item) => {
        const fetchDeeper = async () => {
          let res = await fetch(`${item.url}`);
          let response = await res.json();
    
          let eachPoke = {
            id: response.id,
            name: response.name,
            artwork: response.sprites.other['officialartwork'].front_default,
            stats: response.stats,
          };
    
          fetchedPokemons.push(eachPoke);
        };
        fetchDeeper();
      });
      setPokemonList(fetchedPokemons);
      if (fetchedPokemons) {
        return setLoading(false);
      }
   }
   fetchData()
      .then((res) => setLoading(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log('error', err));
   };
```

PokemonList component below

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { StyledPokemonListContainer } from './PokemonList.styles';
import { PokemonsContext } from '../../../providers/PokemonsProvider';
    
const PokemonList = () => {
  const ctx = useContext(PokemonsContext);
    
  const [, updateState] = useState();
  const forceUpdate = useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);
    
  const { handleSetImgLoaded } = useContext(PokemonsContext);
    
  return (
    <>
    {ctx.currentPokedexOption === 'pokemonList' ? (
        <StyledPokemonListContainer>
          {ctx.pokemonList && ctx.pokemonList.length ? (
            ctx.pokemonList.map((item, i) => (
          <div className="each-pokemon-container" key={i}>
                <div className="poke-id">{item.id}</div>
                <div className="poke-name">{item.name}</div>
                <img className="poke-photo" onLoad={() => handleSetImgLoaded()} src={item ? item.artwork : ''} alt="" />
              </div>
            ))
          ) : (
            <div className="render-info">Hit rerender button</div>
          )}
          {/* {ctx.pokemonList ? <div>{ctx.pokemonList[0].name}</div> : <div>DUPPSKO</div>} */}
          <div className="buttons">
            <button onClick={() => console.log('PREVOIUS')}>Previous</button>
            <button className="rerender-button" onClick={() => forceUpdate()}>
              RERENDER
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => console.log('NEXT')}>Next</button>
          </div>
        </StyledPokemonListContainer>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
    
export default PokemonList;
```

Comment: `I tried to use useEffect in PokemonList component but it didn't work in any way.` Can you please post how you used `useEffect`?

Comment: Can you also try use a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) with your code so others can identify and try help. You can add mock data in a `const`.

Comment: For now I do not use UseEffect in this component. I'm trying to manage by useState. Before I tried use it like useEffect(() => {
change loading}, [ctx.pokemonList]);
I will put it in sandbox as soon as I can

Comment: It looks like you would need to use `useEffect` to watch for changes in state automatically. So I'll take a look at your sandbox link when ready so I can advise further.